# Does there exist a transitive action of $G$ on the set $Gx$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> True or False: Let a group $G$ act on a set $X$, and let $Gx$ denote the orbit of
>   some $x \in X$. Then there exists a transitive action of $G$ on the
>   set $Gx$.

I think this is true because for any $x 
\in X$ we have $Orb_G(x)=X$. However, I am not sure. Is this statement true or false, and why?

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you, yet I don't quite understand why he *also* used $\;Orb(x)\;$ later.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Suppose $y$ and $z$ are in the orbit of $x$. Then you can find elements of $G$ such that ...

Then find an element of $G$ that moves $y$ to $z$.

Comment: ...such that for $g \in G$, $gy=z$?

Comment: Not quite. "$gy=z$" will end the last sentence of your proof. To find the $g$ that works you have to finish the sentence with the "such that" and use the two elements you get to figure out what $g$ has to be.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. The action is a map
$$
G \times X \to X.
$$
Restrict this map to $G \times G x$, to get a map
$$
G \times G x \to X
$$
whose image is easily seen to be $G x$, as for $g, h \in G$ one has
$$
h (g x) = (h g) x \in G x.
$$ 
And then by the very definition
$$
G x = \{ g x : g \in G \}.
$$
 $G$ acts transitively on $G x$.

Comment: This is correct, but not likely to help the OP.

Comment: @EthanBolker, thanks, I'll leave to OP to decide.